# Copying Iterator causes member value to change in c++

Tags: c++, graph, iterator, copy, depth-first-search

I am trying to write an iterator for a graph class in which the iterator proceeds via dfs (depth first search) algorithm. However, I am experiencing problems in copying the iterator, due to which the values of the member variables are replaced with erroneous ones:

```
vector< iterator > depthFirst(node& gn)
{
    vector<  iterator > result;
    unmark();
    auto it = next(_vertices.begin(), gn._index);
    depthFirst_aux(it, result);
    return result;
}
```

As I enter the depthFirst_aux function, and I deference `it` i.e `(*it)` `it->neighbours` (which is one of its member variables of type `vector`) is empty which it shouldn't be. Whereas, other member variables seem to have appropriate values. So basically invoking `_vertices.begin()` and further `next` is not copying all the member variables value properly. So please, can anyone tell me the solution to this.

Edit:I can pin down the problem being that when I debug and check `it` value in the debugger, the `it->_vertices` has changed. Before that everything is perfect. So whatever happens, happens in the 3rd line of the function. Possibly  the `begin` function is sending a copy of the iterator, whereas I need a reference.

Comment: The pool of possible causes is virtually unbounded. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I can pin down the problem being that when I debug and check `it` value in the debugger, the `it->_vertices`  has changed. Before that everything is perfect. So whatever happens, happens in the 3rd line of the function. Possibly the `begin` function is sending a copy of the iterator, whereas I need a reference.

Comment: For all we know the program overruns the stack and goes insane 20 lines earlier, but you don't see visible effects until there. There's little we can do for you.